# Tag Suggestion or randomization

Tags: discussion, user-interface

When I type a question, the dialoguebox under tags has some faint suggestion, that includes suggestion. must include at least one ... like Calculus, ...

Just out of curiosity, is it randomized or is it made sensitive to title, wordings on the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if it is in anyway randomized. But I am pretty sure we can rule out the "tailored to title/body text" alternative.

When I visit the "Ask Question" page I always see "integral, matrices, number theory" suggested (at least I tried it a few times just now). It doesn't matter what I typed in the title and body boxes, nor does it matter whether I typed in those boxes at all.

The above experiment however doesn't rule out possibilities that

- The prompt text could be user specific; so you see something from what I see.
- The prompt text changes over time
- The prompt text is not *random*: it can be generated by a deterministic algorithm.

Comment: Ah yes. You are right. It seems prompt changes over time. I had Linear Algebra sometimes and Calculus othertimes. Now, I have Integral, matrices...